# .NET Core accessing S3: Access Denied

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very new to AWS S3 and have no idea what went wrong in my code.

I'm wanting to develop a backend that takes in a file and uploads it to S3 bucket, but I got `Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied` with the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file) {
    var client = new AmazonS3Client(
        "access key id",
        "secret access key",
        "session token",
        RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2
    );

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest {
            InputStream = memoryStream,
            Key = file.FileName,
            BucketName = "bucket name",
            ContentType = file.ContentType
        };
        var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
        await transferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
    }
    
    return Ok("OK");
}
```

The access key id, secret access key, and session token were taken from aws CLI using this command

```
aws sts get-session-token --duration-seconds 129600
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to use the same AWS STS credentials with the AWSCLI (aws s3 cp ...) to upload a file to the exact same bucket and key?

Comment: Never mind lol, it turns out I didn't give the user the right permission. Just configured it and now it works, but thanks for answering Jarmod!

Comment: Would you share the output of the code of your question?

Comment: This endpoint will ask the user to upload a file and hitting the endpoint will upload the file to the S3 bucket